# Custom header in iis 6.0

Tags: deployment, iis-6, windows-installer

How to add custom header by the msi.
I wanna add custom header in **IIS6.0** at the time of deployment.
How to add custom header automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom header through `adsutil` . see this [How to add custom HTTP Headers to IIS from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637289/how-to-add-custom-http-headers-to-iis-from-the-command-line).

In your MSI you will have to create a `custom action` of type script.

Comment: how are you creating MSI file?

Comment: cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/ROOT/Test/css/HttpCustomHeaders "Cache-Control: max-age=36000"

Comment: when i use it an error appears The path requested could not be found. ErrNumber: -2147024893 (0x80070003) Error Trying To Get the Object: w3svc/1/ROOT/Test/css w3svc/1/ROOT/Test is the virtual directory

i want to apply my script to sub directory css Question i have is it possible to apply to sub directory

Comment: @Sandy - if this answer helped you out then you should mark it as correct and optionally upvote.